# Put tar'd files in a subdirectory

Tags: archiving, tar

I have a directory setup like the following:

```
folder_x
file.y
file.z
```

I would like to create a tar file so that when it's extracted the structure will look something like this:

```
dir_q/folder_x
dir_q/file.y
dir_q/file.z
```

How could I get this to work by using `tar`? For reference, the current command that I'm using is:

```
tar -czf archive.tar.gz file.y file.z folder_x
```

Answer (score 11):

I've never used the --transform option, but I gather it would do what you need:

```
tar -czf archive.tar.gz --transform 's,^,dir_q/,' file.y file.z folder_x
```

Realize the use of `,` instead of `/` as separator, so we can add a trailing slash.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be doing it properly: `file.z` -> `dirfile.z` and `dirfolder_x`. I'll play around with the regex too see if I can get it the way I want it.

Comment: Here's how I do it:
tar -czf archive.tar.gz --transform 's,^,dir_q/,' file.y file.z folder_x

Sed allows , instead of /, avoiding ambiguity when there are forward slashes in your expression.  Normally I would say you can escape the slash with a backslash, but sed (at least, gnu sed) doesn't interpret it correctly.

Comment: tar --transform doesn't seem to work on MacOS

Comment: In MacOS you could install macports and gnutar to get the --transform option.  Or download & compile gnutar yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind creating the new directory...

```
mkdir dir_q;tar -C $_ -xzvf archive.tar.gz
```

alternatively, make a new directory, untar the file to that directory, then re-tar it from the parent directory to include it's name in the extracted version. That way you do not have to remember some super long invocation.